# How can I move my files to a secondary internal harddrive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have two internal harddrives: a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I just added that last HDD. My setup is root and home on the SSD. Because I am running out of space, I want to move my files to the HDD, but I want to keep some files on the SSD because I access them a lot for data analysis.

What is the best way to do this?

I am contemplating symlinking some folders to the HDD. Or can I mount some of the HDD folders on a location in home?

Answer (score 3):

You can do both :-)

I have a system with home as a directory in the root parttion (the simple standard). Alongside that I have a large disk with a **data** partition. I mount that partition via a line in /etc/fstab ('directly', not in home). I have short aliases to get to the directories, that I use often (I use terminal windows a lot), and I have symlinks too.

In the beginning I dual booted with Windows, so I had the NTFS file system in the data partition. But now I use almost only linux, and I have switched to ext4, which is faster (in linux) and also allows more flexible permissions and links.

I have separate backups for the system and the data partition.